How do I access localhost across docker containers?
I have a run config1 like so
docker run  \
--name webapp_postgres \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='abc123'  \
-e POSTGRES_DB="webapp"  \
-p5432:5432  \
-d postgres

and config2 like so
docker run \
--name webapp \
-p8080:8443 \
appname/webapp

Is there a way to allow config2 to access config1 as localhost?
I've tried creating a custom docker network, and placing config1 and config2 in the network via the --net flag, but that doesn't seem to work.
I've also tried --net host for config2 but that disallows publishing ports, so the container gets access to 5432 but then I cant access the container website.
Please note: I am not currently able to change the address the app looks for due to architectural issues, which will be handled later. In moving to docker, I need to have it look for localhost and only localhost, atleast for right now.

You can re-define what IP address localhost maps to within an OS. So theoretically you could point it to the IP of your other container for this specific container, but that could cause some issues. Check out this thread on Superuser.

--net=host for both containers is the way to go and you'll have to accept accessing webapp on port 8443

@DazWilkin I’ll try that later, but last time I wasn’t allowed to access webapp via any port, i.e didn’t use the -p flag with —net

--net=host on both containers binds (both) to the host's network. You get localhost references for both but you lose port mapping (and so must use the container's 8443 port not the remapped 8080)

@DazWilkin unfortunately localhost:8443 and localhost:5432 are not accepting requests

Are you running on Windows?

@DazWilkin macos m1 with linux/arm64 virt enabled in docker

Got an solution, ty for the help troubleshooting @DazWilkin

Can you fix the bug in your application where the database location isn't configurable?  This will also keep you from using a cloud-hosted managed database (an AWS RDS instance will never be localhost for example) or any other case where the application and database aren't exactly the same place.

@DavidMaze that’s planed for later, this was just a temporary solution to make development easy for now

So my catch 22 was that I could get the containers to talk to each other via localhost if they were both under --net host. Unfortunately this meant that they couldn't talk to me, the host machine.
Using docker network was not a solution, as they could communicate with the host over localhost fine, but required different hostnames to talk to each other.
In searching, a discord user linked me to a quote from https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/tutorials/host/, namely:

The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, but is available as a beta feature on Docker Desktop version 4.29 and later for Mac, Windows, and Linux. To enable this feature, navigate to the Features in development tab in Settings, and then select Enable host networking.

So my first step was to update my outdated Docker Desktop to 4.33.1.
Next, I enabled the mentioned Host Networking beta feature (this requires a Docker.com account for some reason, telemetry?)
The rest was easy, I relaunched both configurations using --net host, and now they were able to talk to each other over localhost, as well as talk to the host machine over localhost as well. Success!
